# Экспорт данных из Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Есть готовая импортированная таблица в WordPress, как выделить и экспортировать определенные строки и столбцы из таблицы в excel или pdf.
Так же буду благодарен если поможете с фильтрацией столбцов.
Плагин для отображения стоит TablePress.
Тема The Minimal

Comment: CTRL+C  - CTRL+V ?

Comment: можно и так но это скорее должно работать по методу кнопки сабмита где все выделенные строки отсылаются к серверу то есть на php и там дальше операции. Этот метод я пробовал но из за него у меня пропадает поле поиска по значениям.